# Java Reference to Objects

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have a `Node` class. It has a single field, `Node parentNode.` It's got setters and getters too.

I have 2 nodes: `Node nodeA` and `Node nodeB`.

Here's what I want to do: set `nodeB`'s parent to `nodeA`'s parent, and then set `nodeA`'s parent to null.

1. `nodeB.setParent(nodeA.getParent());`
2. `nodeA.setParent(null);`                  `// bad since nodeB.getParent() will = null`

To achieve the above, must I clone `nodeA,` and then do `nodeB.setParent(nodeAClone.getParent())`?

Comment: What's the problem, exactly, with the code you have proposed? Did it not work for you when you tried it?

Comment: I should've tried it first... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> nodeA.setParent(null); // bad since nodeB.getParent() will = null

No, `nodeB.parent` will not be set to `null`. Java always uses `Pass by Value` and not `pass by reference`. Repeat it 10 times.

And in case you pass references, you pass them by value of references.

---

Let's understand in more detail.

When you do: -

```
nodeB.setParent(nodeA.getParent());
```

you simply create a copy of reference to `nodeA parent`, and store it in `nodeB parent`. So, you have now two references referring to `nodeA parent` object.Now, when you set `nodeA parent` to `null`, it is detached from that `parent`, but `nodeB parent` reference is still there.

Comment: well stated clarification on java's pass by value/reference.

Answer (score 3):

Because nodeX.parent is a reference to an object:

- When you call `nodeB.setParent(nodeA.getParent())` you are saying to nodeB "here is the address of nodeA's parent."
- When you then say `nodeA.setParent(null);` you are saying to nodeA "Forget where your parent lives. Your parent is now nothing."
- You said nothing to nodeB in the second statement, which still has the address to what is now its parent.